# encog - prediction with multiple input types

Tags: java, prediction, encog

I am using encog for predicting time series data just like the sunspot example. My dataset has 3 columns x,y,z and I want to predict next value of x,y,z with an input window size of 3. That is, I want to use 3 set of values of x,y,z. For example, x(t-3), y(t-3), z(t-3),x(t-2), y(t-2), z(t-2),x(t-1), y(t-1), z(t-1) to predict x(t), y(t), z(t). There is no issue for setting the data for training. Below is my code for training:

```
TemporalMLDataSet result = new TemporalMLDataSet(3, 1);

    TemporalDataDescription desc1 = new TemporalDataDescription(new ActivationSIN(),TemporalDataDescription.Type.RAW, true, true);
    TemporalDataDescription desc2 = new TemporalDataDescription(new ActivationSIN(),TemporalDataDescription.Type.RAW, true, true);
    TemporalDataDescription desc3 = new TemporalDataDescription(new ActivationSIN(),TemporalDataDescription.Type.RAW, true, true);

    result.addDescription(desc1);
    result.addDescription(desc2);
    result.addDescription(desc3);

    for (int year = 3; year < train_end; year++)
    {
        TemporalPoint point = new TemporalPoint(3);
        point.setSequence(year);
        point.setData(0, x[year]);
        point.setData(1, y[year]);
        point.setData(2, z[year]);


        result.getPoints().add(point);
    }
    result.generate();
    return result;
```

But I cannot understand how to predict using the MLdata input/ouput. In the sunspots example, there is only one value (1 column) for each data point. But in my case, there are 3 values(x,y,z) for each data point. Below is the code provided in sunspot example for prediction:

```
for (int year = evaluate_start,l=0; year < EVALUATE_END; year++,l++)
    {
        MLData input = new BasicMLData(3);

        for (int i=0;i<input.size();i++){
        input.setData(i, x[(year - 3+ i)]); // how to set values for y and z??
    }

        MLData output = network.compute(input);

        double prediction = output.getData(0);
```

From the code above, the varible input will consists of 3 values of x. But I want one value x, one value of y and one value of z instead of 3 values of only x. Question 1: how can I achieve this??

Now these 3 values will correspond to the window size of 3. But I want to use 3 set of values of x,y,z. For example, x(t-3), y(t-3), z(t-3),x(t-2), y(t-2), z(t-2),x(t-1), y(t-1), z(t-1) to predict x(t), y(t), z(t). So there are 9 values for a window size of 3. In the sunspot example, 3 input neurons correspond to window size of 3. Question 2:  how should my input layer look like in encog?

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: 1. how should I predict 3 columns(x,y,z) using the example code for prediction of sunspots since the prediction code for sunspot use only one column?  2. Does a window size of 3 means 3 input neurons in encog?

Comment: I am in the same boat as you buddy. Did you figure it out? However, I know the answer to your question number 2.

The first parameter of the TemporalMLDataSet object (in your case 3) means that you want to use 3 years to predict 1 year. But, those years are not related to the number of variables per year. That's question number 1 which I don't know as well.